# How to selectively add stylesheets to UIWebView?

Tags: ios, css, uiwebview, stylesheet

I'm trying to write HTML that will cause a UIWebView to apply a device-specific stylesheet when it loads.

In the  element of my HTML template, I have the following Javascript defined:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function()
        {
            var newStylesheetLink = document.createElement('link');
            newStylesheetLink.rel = 'stylesheet';
            newStylesheetLink.type = 'text/css';

            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))
            {
                newStylesheetLink.href='about~iphone.css');
            }
            else
            {
                newStylesheetLink.href='about~ipad.css');
            }

            document.head.appendChild(newStylesheetLink);
        };
    </script>
```

I've verified that this function is indeed being invoked when the UIWebView loads, and that the device detection is working correctly; but the stylesheet referenced by the newStylesheetLink element var is not being applied to the content of the UIWebView (i.e., apparently, it either does not load the referenced CSS file or, if it does, appending it as a child on the head element does not cause the UIWebView's contents to update).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Carl

Answer (score 0):

Well, after much trial and error, I discovered that if instead of setting the href of the link with:

```
newStylesheetLink.href=<value>;
```

I instead set it with:

```
newStylesheetLink.setAttribute('href', <value>);
```

everything works. In other words, if I use the setAttribute method instead of the .href notation, it works. Why this should be so is beyond me, especially since the .rel and .type assignments work just fine. (Could it be that in iOS the setAttribute method resolves the path of the stylesheet in the app's bundle, while the .href assignment doesn't?)

So, this revised script actually works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function()
    {
        var newStylesheetLink = document.createElement('link');

        newStylesheetLink.rel = 'stylesheet';
        newStylesheetLink.type = 'text/css';

        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))
        {
            newStylesheetLink.setAttribute('href', 'about~iphone.css');
        }
        else
        {
            newStylesheetLink.setAttribute('href', 'about~ipad.css');
        }

        document.head.appendChild(newStylesheetLink);
    };
</script>
```